# show smiley icons into an uitextfield

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I would like to show list of emotion icons / smiley icons when tap of a button. on selecting any, i want that icon to placed on my uitextview.

Is there any options to do with iPhone app , if not will it require more time to get it

Please let me know and thanks

Comment: With iOS 5 the user can add the Emoji keyboard to there list of used keyboards. There emoji charters can be used in any textfield, textview, label, ..

Comment: That's nice. Thinking to upgrade my Xcode version.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Take one `UIImage` that looks like `UITextField` and set it on the `UILabel` background image. Once the emoticon is selected, put it on the `UILabel`. Hope that would help you.

Answer (score 4):

**NSAttributedString** is a option to archive your goal.

There is a project you may have a look:

[emotionlabel](http://code.google.com/p/emotionlabel/)

It's based on [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText) project which enables you drawing simple rich text like any HTML document without having to use a UIWebView.